# Nasm dotted labels

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am familiar with TASM but less with NASM. I have read that NASM allows for local labels, which are indicated with a dot before the name. For instance, the code

```
.loop: ;some code
       jmp .loop
```

define a local label whose name is .loop, and the referenced address is used in the later instruction jmp.
However, reading some code examples online I find lines like

```
.label1:
        push label1
        ;other push
```

and I am puzzled because label1 is not defined anywhere (so it must somehow be related with .label1), but I don't understand neither the meaning of such a push nor if the code should be push .label1 . What does `push label1` do?

Comment: That's broken code and doesn't work. Have you tried it? `nasm` complains: _error: symbol label1 undefined._  `push .label1` would work, and would push the address of that label, no surprise there.

Comment: I have downloaded both the source and the assembled+linked code and the .exe seems to work fine, but actually I haven't assembled the code myself since I don't have nasm. I am just reading it to understand the  differences with tasm. So do you confirm that .label1 and label1 are two different labels?

Comment: Yes they are different. It's easy to grab `nasm` it's basically a standalone executable. Would have been faster than asking on here ;)

Comment: Actually the "`.loop:`" can be viewed as defining symbol `root_label.loop`, not `.loop`. And when you use in code symbol `.loop`, nasm will check which is current root, and will search for full `root_label.loop` instead. For example this works: `global foo.bar` `foo:` `.bar:` `nop`, while `global .bar` will report error, local label can't be exported. For short tests/experiments you can use nasm even online: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php (of course only linux sources can be run, but even DOS/windows can be compiled to verify syntax)

Answer (score 11):

The leading dot is NASM's syntax for making local labels, which essentially nest on top of the last ordinary (non-local) label.

```
sum_ints: ; input: ecx is loop counter
    mov eax,0  ; the sum
    jmp .check
    .loopstart:
        add eax,ecx ; add counter to sum
        sub ecx,1 ; decrement counter
        .check:
        cmp ecx,0 ; see if we're done
        jg .loopstart
    ret
```

Here "sum_ints" is the normal top-level label, while .loopstart and .check are local labels.

`.loopstart` turns into `sum_ints.loopstart`, so you can actually refer to dot-labels from outside their scope.  (And this lets NASM put local labels into the object file's symbol table without conflicts.)

---

The details are explained in the NASM manual:
  https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9

Local labels are useful for the same reason that local variables are useful in other languages: it allows you to use short sensible names (like "loop") without polluting the global namespace.