# Assembly too many labels with same name

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am creating a simple code in assembly x64 with nasm, but in my algorithm I need many while and for loops inside my functions. Because of this, my code is full of labels like `loop1`, `loop2`, `loop3`... Is there a way to jump to the next or previous label called `loop` so I can call all those loops as only one label?

Comment: There are at least two solutions: Use NASM [local labels](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9), or use [my anonymous (@@) labels macros](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/8f539fd02c1f/lmacros2.mac#l995). The anon labels are always placed as `@@` and referenced as `@F`, `@B` (or for further jumps `@FF`, etc). But you could modify these macros to allow a label name like `@@loop` and jump to like `@Floop`.

Comment: If you only have a couple loops inside each function, local labels like `.loop` solve that problem.  If you have large functions with many loops per function, think harder about meaningful names for them, like `.search_loop`, `.fill_loop`, etc.  (or just `.search` and `.fill` if you don't also need branches to code that sets up to (re-)run those loops.)  [Nasm dotted labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42474854)

Comment: @ecm the compiler is throwing error when I try to use the `@@` syntax. Could you explain better how to use this?

Comment: @FelipeK.Bernardino You have to copy the macro collection implementation from https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/lmacros/file/8f539fd02c1f/lmacros2.mac#l995 line 995 to line 1230 into your sources, or into a macro/include file that you include. You can just copy my complete macro collection and `%include "lmacros2.mac"` if you want (but some parts are intended for 16-bit 86 Mode). In any case, your sources **must define** enough of these macros before you can use `@@` labels, in front of any use of anonymous labels.

Comment: As it has been already said, you can use macros ```@@```, ```@F```, and ```@B``` for this purpose. Out of curiosity; how did you design your code to have that much loops inside a function call, that you cannot handle labels?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I am trying to make a code to generate the hash code of an arbitrary string. So I need to create many different loops. I could break the function into many other functions, but don't want to do that hahaha